# What are "credit" transactions I see in my credit card bill?

Tags: credit-card, financial-literacy, terminology

I see some transactions on my credit card bill labeled as "credited". They are different from other regular transactions (sometimes labeled as "debit") in a way that makes their nature seem opposite from each other. (Q2: Does that mean I can ***receive*** money through my credit card too?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can deposit money into your credit card. When you make a repayment of your credit card bill you are making a deposit into it and it will show up as a credit on your statement. If you get a refund for an item you returned this will also be listed as a credit on your statement.

Comment: My credit card rewards show up as statement credits too.

Comment: @JohnBensin - do you have your rewards as cash-back or as auto-payment of your card, or is it just the points that show up as credits? Mine show up as credits but in a different section under reward points (and debit reward points if I redeem any rewards during the month).

Comment: My reward points show up in a different section like yours, and I can use them for a range of options. I just chose an automatic credit to my outstanding balance.

Comment: I have one card whose rebate shows as a credit like any payment. Another, attaches a check for the rebate.

Comment: For Q2, I mean more like, can I receive money from someone else

Comment: @laggingreflex - if you give them your credit card details or the payment details from your statement, then yes you should be able to receive money on your credit card from someone else.

Comment: "**or the payment details**" -- are you saying that only payments that have been charged from my card can be reverted, and in that sense alone could someone pay me? ..Or can I just give someone my card number and they could make a payment of any arbitrary amount into it?

Comment: @laggingreflex -  when you get your credit card statement it should have the total balance owing, the minimum payment due and the payment methods (for example some reference number to use when making payments). You need to provide the details of one of these payment methods for someone to make a payment on your card. And anyone should be able to make a payment with these details.